# XSD - Use of Any in a nested complex type

Tags: xsd

In the below XSD, when I try to define elements under AdditionalInfo in the extended schema, I get an error saying "Invalid particle by restriction". Can someone please help me to achieve this objective of having a nested complex type where I can restrict the elements in the inheriting type?

I saw the link [xsd sequence of any type of element that is an extension of specific complex type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2007221/xsd-sequence-of-any-type-of-element-that-is-an-extension-of-specific-complex-typ) but my question is a bit different.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xs:schema targetNamespace="http://tempuri.org/XMLSchema.xsd"
elementFormDefault="qualified"
xmlns="http://tempuri.org/XMLSchema.xsd"
xmlns:mstns="http://tempuri.org/XMLSchema.xsd"
xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
>
<xs:complexType name="BaseActivityWithIncidentId">
<xs:sequence>
  <xs:element name="Category" type="xs:string"/>
  <xs:element name="SubCategory" type="xs:string"/>
  <xs:element name="IncidentId" type="xs:long"/>
  <xs:element name="ActivityTime" type="xs:dateTime"></xs:element>
  <xs:element name="Remarks" type="xs:string"></xs:element>
  <xs:element name="AdditionalInfo">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:any minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
</xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>

  <xs:complexType name="PartInstalledRequest">
<xs:complexContent>
  <xs:restriction base="BaseActivityWithIncidentId">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element name="Category" type="xs:string" fixed="Part"/>
      <xs:element name="SubCategory" type="xs:string" fixed="Installed"/>
      <xs:element name="IncidentId" type="xs:long"/>
      <xs:element name="ActivityTime" type="xs:dateTime"></xs:element>
      <xs:element name="Remarks" type="xs:string"></xs:element>
      <xs:element name="AdditionalInfo">
        <xs:complexType>
          <xs:sequence>    
            <xs:element name="PartName" type="xs:string"></xs:element>
            <xs:element name="PartNumber" type="xs:string"></xs:element>
          </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
      </xs:element>
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:restriction>
</xs:complexContent>
  </xs:complexType>
</xs:schema>
```

I am pasting the complete code that is having problems. I don't know Megha why you did not face this problem, but you can try this code

```
string baseSchema = @"<?xml version=""1.0"" encoding=""utf-8""?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs=""http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"">
<xs:complexType name=""BaseActivityWithIncidentId"">
<xs:sequence>
<xs:element name=""Category"" type=""xs:string""/>
<xs:element name=""SubCategory"" type=""xs:string""/>
<xs:element name=""IncidentId"" type=""xs:long""/>
<xs:element name=""ActivityTime"" type=""xs:dateTime""></xs:element>
<xs:element name=""Remarks"" type=""xs:string""></xs:element>
<xs:element name=""AdditionalInfo"">
<xs:complexType>
<xs:sequence>
<xs:any minOccurs=""0"" maxOccurs=""unbounded""/>
</xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
</xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
</xs:schema>";
string inheritedSchema = @"<?xml version=""1.0"" encoding=""utf-8""?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs=""http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"" 
id=""PartInstalled"">
<xs:include id=""BaseSchema"" schemaLocation=""BaseSchema.xsd"" />
<xs:element name=""Activity"">
<xs:complexType>
<xs:complexContent>
<xs:restriction base=""BaseActivityWithIncidentId"">
<xs:sequence>
<xs:element name=""Category"" type=""xs:string"" fixed=""Part""/>
<xs:element name=""SubCategory"" type=""xs:string"" fixed=""Installed""/>
<xs:element name=""IncidentId"" type=""xs:long""/>
<xs:element name=""ActivityTime"" type=""xs:dateTime""></xs:element>
<xs:element name=""Remarks"" type=""xs:string""></xs:element>
<xs:element name=""AdditionalInfo"">
<xs:complexType>
<xs:sequence>    
<xs:element name=""PartName"" type=""xs:string""></xs:element>
<xs:element name=""PartNumber"" type=""xs:string""></xs:element>
</xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
</xs:sequence>
</xs:restriction>
</xs:complexContent>
</xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
</xs:schema>";
XmlSchemaSet schemas = new XmlSchemaSet();
var schema = schemas.Add("", 
XmlReader.Create(new StringReader(inheritedSchema)));
schemas.Add("", XmlReader.Create(new StringReader(baseSchema)));
schemas.Compile();
string xml = @"<Activity>
<Category>Part</Category>
<SubCategory>Installed</SubCategory>
<IncidentId>1</IncidentId>
<ActivityTime>2015-08-11T15:00:00.587Z</ActivityTime>
<Remarks>123</Remarks>
<AdditionalInfo>
<PartName>CR</PartName>
<PartNumber>CR123</PartNumber>
</AdditionalInfo>
</Activity>";
XDocument doc = XDocument.Parse(xml);
string msg = "";
doc.Validate(schemas, (o, e) =>
{
msg += e.Message + Environment.NewLine;
});
Console.WriteLine(msg == "" ? "Document is valid" : 
"Document invalid: "+     msg);
Console.ReadLine();
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to define a nested complex type you can do something like this. You can define a new complex type just like "PartInstalledRequest" and use it as a type in your AddtionalInfo.

```
<xs:complexType name="BaseActivityWithIncidentId">
   <xs:sequence>
     <xs:element name="Category" type="xs:string"/>
     <xs:element name="SubCategory" type="xs:string"/>
     <xs:element name="IncidentId" type="xs:long"/>
     <xs:element name="ActivityTime" type="xs:dateTime"></xs:element>
     <xs:element name="Remarks" type="xs:string"></xs:element>
     <xs:element name="AdditionalInfo" type="AddtionalType" minOccurs="0"
               maxOccurs="unbounded">   
     </xs:element>
     </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>  
  <xs:complexType name="AddtionalType">
    <xs:complexContent>
       <xs:sequence>    
          <xs:element name="PartName" type="xs:string"></xs:element>
          <xs:element name="PartNumber" type="xs:string"></xs:element>
      </xs:sequence>    
    </xs:complexContent>
  </xs:complexType>
```

Comment: The whole point to have "Any" type under AdditionalInfo was that we don't know the type of elements that will be present under it, for example a Parts Deinstalled request could have different elements. So the solution that you suggest will not work for me

Comment: Do you mean you want the schema to handle some kind of dynamic contents?

Comment: Hi..I checked your xsd again and I saw that i get the error ""Invalid particle by restriction" when I have by mistake defined the schema definition i.e. this line <xs:schema targetNamespace="http://tempuri.org/XMLSchema.xsd"
  elementFormDefault="qualified"  twice by mistake due to copy and paste on the validator. Can you check if you are not making the same mistake. If I remove that your xsd validates fine

Comment: I have edited and pasted the complete code, please try Megha

Comment: @KrishanArora: one problem I definitely see in your code is that you are using restriction base and than adding additional elements to your AdditionalInfo in your derived class. But when you use restriction base , the base type cannot be changed or extended; only the elements can be restricted

Comment: So, what is the solution - if I don't use the restriction base, I anyways can't achieve what I want. Also, in the base class, I already have put in a clause saying AdditionalInfo can contain any number of elements, in the in the inherited class I am just defining the elements

Comment: yes thats right but using restriction base  will not allow you too add or subtract elements ....I was working on it today as well to see if there is any way to achieve what u want too but couldnt figure out a way...I will try again nd let u know ...perhaps we can chat